# HTML input font-size is greater when defined as inherit

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-size

I am using Chrome and default font size is `16px` as default.

I have an idea to adjust `font-size` according to screen `width` via media queries.

I saw some CSS experts adjusting default `16px` font size to `1.6rem` based system.

So idea behind scence is to equalize `1rem` to `10px` and use everything as `rem` then if needed to adjust something change only `font-size` so all measurements will change at same ratio.

See this example

```css
* {
  font-size: inherit;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>

<input type="text" value="Hello">
```

Can anybody explain why `font-size` in `input` is greater than `p` ?

Also if I try to obtain `font-size` in dev tools I can't get any value.

If I try to get it via JavaScript like this

`document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].style.fontSize`

I get `''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a null result on looking at the style because the inline style has not been set.

The two Hellos are not different font sizes - both are 16px, but the paragraph is Times New Roman and the input it Arial - set by the default within the browser, at least on my inspection in Chrome/Edge on Windows10.

It is worth using your browser's inspect facility to see exactly what is setting each of the styles, and it will show you the computed style as well.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have applied same font family to both elements and they are all became same size. Thanks for help.